# In Using pfSense HAProxy - to check the url if it has a sub domain name

Tags: haproxy, regex

I have a wildcard Cert and need to direct any sub domain name that does not exist to a custom 503 error page and don’t want to use the Frontend’s Error files feature nor its default 503 page. I want my Backend’s to handle all error pages, but on the server side.

I see in the Access Control lists / Table / Expression has Host regex, Path regex, Url parameter contains. Which one can I use to provide me the ability to check if there is a sub name or chars for example a user type in, (asdas, about, help, etc,…).kohanyim.com.

And if so, I’m really rusty on my regex syntax and can you provide examples I can use?

Would very much appreciate it, Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the [default_backend](http://docs.haproxy.org/2.5/configuration.html#4-default_backend) operator. Basically send anything that doesn't hit another ACL to a specific backend.